# undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

Tags: c++, c++11

Can anyone help me with this error ?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

class ConfigLoader
{
public:
    ConfigLoader():loadedConfigFile(YAML::LoadFile("./home/muasad/Desktop/magna_mdf_reader/Config_file.yaml"))
    {

    }

private:

    YAML::Node loadedConfigFile;
};
```

> error: undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'

Comment: You should show your compile and link command. You are likely missing the YAML library or it was placed in the wrong position in the compile/link command.